# logic error in blackjack game - visual basic

Tags: logic, blackjack

I have been working on a blackjack project for school and I am encountering an annoying logic error that I cannot seem to track down. the Players score is not adding up right when an ace is involved. I coded it so that the ace should change from a value of 11 to 1 when the player draws a card and their score is over 21. any advice? Any way to improve my coding in general would be great as well. Thanks.

```
Private Sub ButtonDraw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
ButtonDraw.Click

    counter = counter + 1
    Dim bust As Integer = 21


    ' holds the numeric value for the players cards
    Dim card1 As Integer
    Dim card2 As Integer
    Dim card3 As Integer
    Dim card4 As Integer
    Dim card5 As Integer


    If counter = 1 Then

        'generates a value between 1 and 14 for the card
        card1 = random.Next(2, 15)

        'after getting card value this if statement determines if it is a 
face card and outputs the appropriate face value
        If card1 = 11 Then
            card1 = 10
            LabelCard1.Text = "J"
        ElseIf card1 = 12 Then
            card1 = 10
            LabelCard1.Text = "Q"
        ElseIf card1 = 13 Then
            card1 = 10
            LabelCard1.Text = "K"
        ElseIf card1 = 1 Then
            LabelCard1.Text = "A"
        ElseIf card1 = 14 Then
            card1 = 11
            LabelCard1.Text = "A"
        Else
            LabelCard1.Text = card1
        End If

        'displays the players card
        LabelCard1.Visible = True

        playerScore = playerScore + card1

        'automatically moves to card 2 since you draw 2 cards each game
        counter = counter + 1

    End If

    If counter = 2 Then

        card2 = random.Next(2, 15)

        If card2 = 11 Then
            card2 = 10
            LabelCard2.Text = "J"
        ElseIf card2 = 12 Then
            card2 = 10
            LabelCard2.Text = "Q"
        ElseIf card2 = 13 Then
            card2 = 10
            LabelCard2.Text = "K"
        ElseIf card2 = 1 Then
            LabelCard2.Text = "A"
        ElseIf card2 = 14 Then
            card2 = 11
            LabelCard2.Text = "A"
        Else
            LabelCard2.Text = card2
        End If


        'totals the player score
        playerScore = playerScore + card2

        'enables stay button
        ButtonStay.Enabled = True

        'displays player score in green text for 21, red for bust, and black 
for under
        If playerScore = 21 Then
            LabelPlayerScore.ForeColor = Color.Green
        ElseIf playerScore > 21 Then
            LabelPlayerScore.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Else
            LabelPlayerScore.ForeColor = Color.Black
        End If

        'updates the player score
        LabelPlayerScore.Text = playerScore

        'displays the players card
        LabelCard2.Visible = True



    End If

    If counter = 3 Then

        card3 = random.Next(2, 15)

        If card3 = 11 Then
            card3 = 10
            LabelCard3.Text = "J"
        ElseIf card3 = 12 Then
            card3 = 10
            LabelCard3.Text = "Q"
        ElseIf card3 = 13 Then
            card3 = 10
            LabelCard3.Text = "K"
        ElseIf card3 = 1 Then
            LabelCard3.Text = "A"
        ElseIf card3 = 14 Then
            card3 = 11
            LabelCard3.Text = "A"
        Else
            LabelCard3.Text = card3
        End If

        playerScore = playerScore + card3

        'changes the ace from an 11 to a 1 value if score exceeds 21
        If playerScore > bust Then
            If card1 = 11 Then
                card1 = 1
                playerScore = card1 + card2 + card3
            End If
            If card2 = 11 Then
                card2 = 1
                playerScore = card1 + card2 + card3
            End If
            If card3 = 11 Then
                card3 = 1
                playerScore = card1 + card2 + card3
            End If
        End If



        'changes the color of the players score if 21 or bust
        If playerScore = 21 Then
            LabelPlayerScore.ForeColor = Color.Green
        ElseIf playerScore > 21 Then
            LabelPlayerScore.ForeColor = Color.Red
        ElseIf playerScore < 21 Then
            LabelPlayerScore.ForeColor = Color.Black
        End If

        LabelPlayerScore.Text = playerScore

        LabelCard3.Visible = True

        'if player goes over 21 automatically updates loss counter and 
disables stay button. displays bust msg
        If playerScore > 21 Then
            losses += 1
            LabelLoseCounter.Text = losses
            ButtonStay.Enabled = False
            ButtonDraw.Enabled = False
            ButtonPlayAgain.Enabled = True
            Dim response = MessageBox.Show("You bust!", "Bust", 
MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            If response = 4 Then
                ButtonPlayAgain.PerformClick()
            End If
        End If

    End If

    If counter = 4 Then

        card4 = random.Next(2, 15)

        If card4 = 11 Then
            card4 = 10
            LabelCard4.Text = "J"
        ElseIf card4 = 12 Then
            card4 = 10
            LabelCard4.Text = "Q"
        ElseIf card4 = 13 Then
            card4 = 10
            LabelCard4.Text = "K"
        ElseIf card4 = 1 Then
            LabelCard4.Text = "A"
        ElseIf card4 = 14 Then
            card4 = 11
            LabelCard4.Text = "A"
        Else
            LabelCard4.Text = card4
        End If

        playerScore = playerScore + card4

        'changes the ace from an 11 to a 1 value if score exceeds 21
        If playerScore > bust Then
            If card1 = 11 Then
                card1 = 1
                playerScore = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4
            End If
            If card2 = 11 Then
                card2 = 1
                playerScore = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4
            End If
            If card3 = 11 Then
                card3 = 1
                playerScore = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4
            End If
            If card4 = 11 Then
                card4 = 1
                playerScore = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4
            End If
        End If



        'changes the color of the players score if 21 or bust
        If playerScore = 21 Then
            LabelPlayerScore.ForeColor = Color.Green
        ElseIf playerScore > 21 Then
            LabelPlayerScore.ForeColor = Color.Red
        ElseIf playerScore < 21 Then
            LabelPlayerScore.ForeColor = Color.Black
        End If


        LabelPlayerScore.Text = playerScore

        LabelCard4.Visible = True


        'if player goes over 21 automatically updates loss counter and 
disables stay button
        If playerScore > bust Then
            losses += 1
            LabelLoseCounter.Text = losses
            ButtonStay.Enabled = False
            ButtonDraw.Enabled = False
            ButtonPlayAgain.Enabled = True
            Dim response = MessageBox.Show("You bust!", "Bust", 
MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            If response = 4 Then
                ButtonPlayAgain.PerformClick()
            End If
        End If

    End If

    If counter = 5 Then

        card5 = random.Next(2, 15)

        If card5 = 11 Then
            card5 = 10
            LabelCard5.Text = "J"
        ElseIf card5 = 12 Then
            card5 = 10
            LabelCard5.Text = "Q"
        ElseIf card5 = 13 Then
            card5 = 10
            LabelCard5.Text = "K"
        ElseIf card5 = 1 Then
            LabelCard5.Text = "A"
        ElseIf card5 = 14 Then
            card5 = 11
            LabelCard5.Text = "A"
        Else
            LabelCard5.Text = card5
        End If

        playerScore = playerScore + card5


        'changes the ace from an 11 to a 1 value if score exceeds 21
        If playerScore > bust Then
            If card1 = 11 Then
                card1 = 1
                playerScore = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4 + card5
            End If
            If card2 = 11 Then
                card2 = 1
                playerScore = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4 + card5
            End If
            If card3 = 11 Then
                card3 = 1
                playerScore = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4 + card5
            End If
            If card4 = 11 Then
                card4 = 1
                playerScore = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4 + card5
            End If
            If card5 = 11 Then
                card5 = 1
                playerScore = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4 + card5
            End If
        End If


        'changes the color of the players score if 21 or bust
        If playerScore = 21 Then
            LabelPlayerScore.ForeColor = Color.Green
        ElseIf playerScore > 21 Then
            LabelPlayerScore.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Else
            LabelPlayerScore.ForeColor = Color.Black
        End If

        LabelPlayerScore.Text = playerScore

        LabelCard5.Visible = True

        'if player goes over 21 automatically updates loss counter and 
disables stay button
        If playerScore > 21 Then
            losses += 1
            LabelLoseCounter.Text = losses
            ButtonStay.Enabled = False
            ButtonDraw.Enabled = False
            ButtonPlayAgain.Enabled = True
            Dim response = MessageBox.Show("You bust!", "Bust", 
MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            If response = 4 Then
                ButtonPlayAgain.PerformClick()
            End If
        Else
            wins += 1
            LabelLoseCounter.Text = wins
            ButtonStay.Enabled = False
            ButtonDraw.Enabled = False
            ButtonPlayAgain.Enabled = True
            Dim response = MessageBox.Show("Winner, Winner, Chicken 
Dinner!!", "Winner!", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, 
MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            If response = 4 Then
                ButtonPlayAgain.PerformClick()
            End If
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you debugged it line by line to see what is going wrong? What exactly happens, what input etc? Also learn to deduplicate code by using functions etc. There's no need to have several blocks of code doing the same thing with just different variables when there could be just one.

Comment: The pseudocode would be `if handTotal <= 11 and hand.contains(ace) then actualHandTotal = handTotal + 10`.

Comment: What debugger are you using to step through the code or set watch points?

Comment: I am not sure what watch points are but I am using visual studio 2010. If I start with an ace in the first 2 cards the value of 11 is never changed to a 1. If I start with 2 aces I have 22. I dont know what I missed. The aces should automatically change if the players hand exceeds 21.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `playerScore > bust` check when `counter = 2`

To fit in with your coding style, you'd need to add code like this at around line 80:

```
   If playerScore > bust Then
        If card1 = 11 Then
            card1 = 1
            playerScore = card1 + card2
        End If
        If card2 = 11 Then
            card2 = 1
            playerScore = card1 + card2
        End If
    End If
```

This is probably what you've missed compared to your intention.

This might not get things as you would want though.  If the score is bust, not all aces have to be converted to score 1, have you considered that in the program logic?

Thinking wider, there is a lot of repeated code written here.

Doing things step by step, the first thing to look into would be storing the cards in an array or list and then using `For` or `For Each` to perform the tasks on each one rather than typing the same code again.

Next step after that would be to use Functions or Sub[routines] to gather up common code so you only have to write it once, but call it a number of times to produce the logic you need.

Good Luck with your learning to code :-)